# Getting location of where a user clicks on a windows form with many controls

Tags: vb.net

I wish to get the location of where a user clicks on a windows form. However, the form has a large number of picture boxes which are all created at run time. As such the code provided below does not work as it only returns the coordinates of the click when the user clicks on no other control than just the form.

```
Private Sub Board_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick

        Label1.Text = e.X
        Label2.Text = e.Y

End Sub
```

Any advice on how to get the coordinates of where the click was performed on the form regardless of the click happening on a picture box will be appreciated.

Comment: When you create a new PictureBox control, add a handler to its `MouseDown` event. Use the same handler for all these controls. The `sender` object of the event handler references the control that was selected/clicked. Use `DirectCast()` to cast `sender` to `PictureBox` (e.g., `dim pBox as PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)`). The mouse coordinates are related to this control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now in each UI / control you click you have your coordinates;).

Call the method that associates the controls with the "click" event in the Form.Load and in each click you have the coordinates of the control you clicked

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddClickHandlerToAnyControl(Me)
End Sub


    Sub AddClickHandlerToAnyControl(mCtrl As Control)

        If mCtrl IsNot Nothing Then
            AddHandler mCtrl.Click, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                        Dim currentCtrl As Object = sender

                                        Dim xLeft As Integer = 0
                                        Dim yTop As Integer = 0

                                        While (currentCtrl IsNot Nothing)
                                            xLeft += CType(currentCtrl, Control).Location.X
                                            yTop += CType(currentCtrl, Control).Location.Y
                                            currentCtrl = CType(currentCtrl, Control).Parent
                                        End While

                                        MsgBox("X : " & xLeft & " Y : " & yTop)

                                        Console.WriteLine("Left from Form = " & xLeft)
                                        Console.WriteLine("Top  from Form = " & yTop)
                                    End Sub



            If mCtrl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                For Each child In mCtrl.Controls
                    AddClickHandlerToAnyControl(child)
                Next
            End If

        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly for all the controls except the picture boxes, when clicked they do not display the location. Any idea why?

Comment: :) I'm glad to hear that. Have fun